# Creating folders in gerrit base path?

Tags: gerrit

I created a git folder and named git and configured it with gerrit . After gerrit installation , All Projects.git repository appeared in the git folder . I want to create a repository in a folder inside git folder . I gave the command

ssh -p 29418 reviewboardname gerrit create-project folder1/first .git

In the git folder a folder1 was created and inside that first.git repo is created .

Now I take a git clone of first.git repository and add some changes . I push the changes for review with command

git push reviewboard/gerrit/folder1/first HEAD:refs/for/master

Now I login to gerrit web GUI and got to open changes . I click on this pushed change but I cannot see it . It says code review error or Bad command.
Please give a solution . The Problem does not exist with any repository created in git folder parallel to All projects

I am the Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution . Allowing encoded slashes is not required in gerrit files . It needs to be added in catalina .

Added the line

```
  org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

in /etc/tomcat7/catalina.properties and then restarted tomcat7.

The issue is solved and repositories inside folders in gerrit base path are working fine .

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Gerrit you are running, or if you are behind an Apache proxy, but I suspect this is caused by the proxy settings required with 2.6.  See http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-reverseproxy.html, specifically the `AllowEncodedSlashes On` and `ProxyPass .. nocanon` lines.